# C# Connecting Through Proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

I work in a office which requires all connections to be made through a specific http proxy. I need to write a simple application to query some values from a webserver - it's easy if there were no proxy. How can I make the C# application proxy-aware? How can I make any sort of connection through a proxy?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This is easily achieved either programmatically, in your code, or declaratively in either the web.config or the app.config.

You can programmatically create a proxy like so:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("[ultimate destination of your request]");
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("[your proxy address]", [your proxy port number]);
myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
request.Proxy = myproxy;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

You're basically assigning the `WebProxy` object to the `request` object's `proxy` property.  This `request` will then use the `proxy` you define.

To achieve the same thing declaratively, you can do the following:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy
      proxyaddress="http://[your proxy address and port number]"
      bypassonlocal="false"
    />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

within your web.config or app.config.   This sets a default proxy that all http requests will use.  Depending upon exactly what you need to achieve, you may or may not require some of the additional attributes of the [defaultProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) / [proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa91de1e.aspx) element, so please refer to the documentation for those.

Comment: in programatical example, you did not set the port, WHY?

Comment: @Skuta - No particular reason.  That was merely an oversight as in that example, I'm using the constructor which takes the URL (as a string) and a boolean to determine if local addresses are bypassed.  If you need a specific port number, it might be better to use the overloaded constructor that allows the URL (as a string) and the port number (as an Int32), then set the `BypassProxyOnLocal` property to True (if required) immediately afterwards.

Comment: @Skuta - I have edited my post to clarify this and to ensure that the programmatic and declarative examples are actually doing the same thing!

Comment: great example.  How to achieve the same for TcpClient ?  I have used TcpClient to TEST some connection but now I want to make sure it works behind the proxy.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using `WebClient`, it has a [Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy%28VS.80%29.aspx) property you can use.

As other have mentioned, there are several ways to automate proxy setting detection/usage

Web.Config:

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
     <proxy usesystemdefault="true" bypassonlocal="true" />
   </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Use of the WebProxy class as described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fze2ytx2.aspx).

---

You can also cofigure the proxy settings directly (config or code) and your app will then use those.

Web.Config:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy
      proxyaddress="http://[proxy address]:[proxy port]"
      bypassonlocal="false"
    />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("[proxy address]:[proxy port]", false);
request.Proxy = myproxy;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want the app to use the system default proxy, add this to your Application.exe.config (where application.exe is the name of your application):

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
   <proxy usesystemdefault="true" bypassonlocal="true" />
   </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

More details can be found on in the [MSDN article on System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309410(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: Note:  The: <system.net> section goes inside the <configuration> section or the exe.config file.  This got the proxy stuff working in a simple console app I cooked up.

Answer (score 7):

Try this code. Call it before making any http requests. The code will use the proxy from your Internet Explorer Settings - one thing though, I use `proxy.Credentials = ....` because my proxy server is an NTLM authenticated Internet Acceleration Server. Give it a whizz.

```
static void setProxy()
{
    WebProxy proxy = (WebProxy)WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
    if(proxy.Address != null)
    {
        proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(proxy.Address, proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal, proxy.BypassList, proxy.Credentials);
    }
}
```

Comment: `WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy` is obsolete since Framework 4.5 and this method returns null. Better think before using`CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`. If you had put something in CredentialCache and your proxy require such credentials, then it should work. Otherwise it will not help.

Answer (score 7):

This one-liner works for me:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

`CredentialCache.DefaultNetWorkCredentials` is the proxy settings set in Internet Explorer.

`WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials` is used for all internet connectivity in the application.

Comment: "CredentialCache.DefaultNetWorkCredentials is the proxy settings set in Internet Explorer". Is this still the case? I can't find anywhere in Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings to write a username and password.

Comment: From the docs: "For a client-side application, these are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) of the user running the application."

Comment: This answer may have aged a bit poorly, but I'm pretty sure it was true for 2015 windows

Answer (score 4):

Foole's code worked perfectly for me, but in .NET 4.0, don't forget to check if Proxy is NULL, which means no proxy configured (outside corporate environment)

So here's the code that solved my problem with our corporate proxy

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
if (web.Proxy != null)
    web.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Answer (score 3):

This code has worked for me:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Answer (score 0):

Automatic proxy detection is a process by which a Web proxy server is identified by the
system and used to send requests on behalf of the client. This feature is also known as 
Web Proxy Auto-Discovery (WPAD). When automatic proxy detection is enabled, the system 
attempts to locate a proxy configuration script that is responsible for returning the set of proxies that can be used for the request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fze2ytx2.aspx

Comment: How does this answer the question?  How can the OP put this information to use?

Answer (score 0):

```
            var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb() { AutoDetectEncoding = false, OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2") };

            WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8888", false);
            NetworkCredential cred = (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            var document = getHtmlWeb.Load("URL", "GET", myproxy, cred);
```

Comment: Its is preferable to write an explanation of your solution and not just post code. Can you edit in some text that would help the reader?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use an example to add to the answers above.

I ran into proxy issues while trying to install packages via **Web Platform Installer**

That too uses a config file which is **WebPlatformInstaller.exe.config**

I tried the edits suggest in [this IIS forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1158971.aspx?Help%20Web%20Platform%20Installer%20Problem) which is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>  
  <system.net>    
     <defaultProxy enabled="True" useDefaultCredentials="True"/>      
   </system.net>
</configuration>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>  
   <system.net>    
     <defaultProxy>      
          <proxy 
               proxyaddress="http://yourproxy.company.com:80" 
               usesystemdefault="True"
               autoDetect="False" />    
     </defaultProxy>  
   </system.net>
</configuration>
```

**None of these worked.**

What worked for me was this -

```
<system.net>    
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
      <module type="WebPI.Net.AuthenticatedProxy, WebPI.Net, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79a8d77199cbf3bc" />
    </defaultProxy>  
 </system.net>
```

The module needed to be registered with Web Platform Installer in order to use it.