# How to specifiy proxy settings for SSRS Winforms Control

Tags: c#, proxy, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am using the SSRS WinForms client control to display reports in an app. User's behind proxies are getting a 407 (proxy authentication) error. How do I specify proxy settings for the request? i.e. proxy server, username & password. I was expecting it to be similar to the HttpRequest and WebProxy.

This is helpful [C# Connecting Through Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-connecting-through-proxy) however I need to specify proxy settings on a per SSRS request basis.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems the only way is to use the <defaultProxy> element in the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the proxy settings  by using reporting web services.

- Add the reporting web reference to your project. The URL of the web service is :

> http://servername/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx

- In the code calling the web service.

> byte[] report = null;
>
> ```
>         //create an instance of the reporting service web reference
>         var reportReference = new ReportExecutionService();
>
>         <strong>//Set your proxy settings
>          reportReference.Proxy = new WebProxy("address:port");
>
>
>         //create a credential that will be used to authenticate again the
> ```
>
> reporting services
>               var credential = new NetworkCredential("username",
>   "password", "domainName");
>
> ```
>         reportReference.Credentials =
> ```
>
> credential;
>
> ```
>         reportReference.PreAuthenticate =
> ```
>
> true;
>
> ```
>         //the virtual path to the report
>         string virtualPath = "/Folder/ReportName";
> ```
>
> ```
>         //Specify the device info
>         string deviceInfo =
>             "<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar><Parameters>False</Parameters><DocMap>True</DocMap><Zoom>100</Zoom></DeviceInfo>";
>
>         //Create an array of parameters, for example our report needs 2 parameters
>         var parameters = new ParameterValue[2];
>
>         //Specify the value for the parameter
>         var startDateParameter = new ParameterValue();
>         startDateParameter.Name = "StartDate";
>         startDateParameter.Value = "01/01/2008";
>
>         parameters[0] = startDateParameter;
>
>         var endDateParameter = new ParameterValue();
>         endDateParameter.Name = "EndDate";
>         endDateParameter.Value = "31/12/2008";
>
>         parameters[1] = endDateParameter;
>
>         //Create variables for the remainder of the parameters
>
>         string extension = string.Empty;
>
>         ExecutionHeader executionHeader = null;
>
>         reportReference.ExecutionHeaderValue =
> ```
>
> executionHeader;
>
> ```
>         reportReference.LoadReport(virtualPath,
> ```
>
> null);
>
> ```
>         reportReference.SetExecutionParameters(parameters,
> ```
>
> "en-AU");
>
> ```
>         try
>         {
>             //Execute the report
>             string[] streamIDs;
>             Warning[] warning = null;
>             string encoding;
>             string mimeType;
>             string format = "PDF";
>
>
>             <strong>//Execute the report
>             report = reportReference.Render(format,
> ```
>
> deviceInfo, out extension, out
>   mimeType, out encoding,
>                                                   out warning, out streamIDs);
>
> ```
>             using (var fileStream = new FileStream("myReport.PDF", FileMode.Create))
>             {
>                 fileStream.Write(report, 0,
> ```
>
> report.Length);
>
> ```
>                 fileStream.Close();
>             }
> ```
>
> **>                 Process.Start("myReport.pdf");**
>
> ```
>         }
>         catch (SoapException exception)
>         {
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to entirely re-write the SSRS Winforms control. I want to be able to specify the proxy settings for the existing one.