# Web Request through Proxy using RestSharp

Tags: windows-phone-7, restsharp

I'm trying to make a webrequest through a proxy on Windows phone 7. From what I can see the Compact Framework does not include the configuring of a proxy for the HttpWebRequest object. I tried using RestSharp but the RestClient also does not allow this. I've also tried configuring the Internet Options on my local machine to use a proxy, hopping that the same options will apply on my Windows Phone Emulator. That didn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 23):

Under "configuration" section in Web.config add this:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"></defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

(for more more info - [MSDN - defaultProxy Element (Network Settings)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: This just fixed a problem I've been having for 3 days. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845404/not-able-to-connect-to-website-urls-from-asp-net-webapi-action-methods/27174481#27174481

Answer (score 22):

For people coming from Google looking how to set a proxy with RestSharp, if you are not on Windows Phone, at least as of version 104.4.0 you can do the following:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com")
client.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.example.com")
```

Don't know whether this would work on Windows Phone since I am not familiar with the framework there; since the title of the question did not contain Windows Phone I thought that many like myself would end up here, just searching about how to setup the proxy with RestSharp.

Comment: i had tried the above per Stefano (using webProxy with restSharp's restClient - kept getting proxy connection issues). instead i ended up dumping that and just editing my app.config by adding in this:

  `<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy autoDetect="False" bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://myproxy.domain.com:8080" usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>`

received the idea from this post on SO [C# Connecting Through Proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy).

Comment: i understand this doesn't directly answer the win 7 original question, but thought i would share in case another fellow restSharp user was struggling with the webProxy issue.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this in RestSharp v107? I've used it before with v106 but with v107 it tells me client.Proxy is not valid. I was going to downgrade to v106 but I see it has a know vulnerability.

Comment: @Caverman Checkout my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71271696/8644294

Answer (score 6):

In RestSharp v107, you can set Proxy using options object.

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://api.myorg.com") {
    Proxy = GetWebProxy() // <-- Right here.
    ThrowOnAnyError = true,
    Timeout = 1000
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```

Method to return `WebProxy` object:

```
public static WebProxy GetWebProxy()
{
    var proxyUrl = "http://proxy-name.companydomain.com:9090/";
    // First create a proxy object
    var proxy = new WebProxy()
    {
        Address = new Uri(proxyUrl),
        BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
        //UseDefaultCredentials = true, // This uses: Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        //*** These creds are given to the proxy server, not the web server ***
        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
        //Credentials = new NetworkCredential("proxyUserName", "proxyPassword")
    };

    return proxy;
}
```

Reference: https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```
String url = "some url";

IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
RestClient client = new RestClient(url);
{
Proxy = proxy,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Some example using a method and a class:
The call:

```
            var client = new RestClient(urlbase);
            if(myConfigInstance.ProxyActive) {
                 client.Proxy = GetWebProxy(myConfigInstance);
            }
```

and the method:

```
  public static WebProxy GetWebProxy(ProxySettings proxySettings)
    {
        WebProxy proxy;
        try
        {
            proxy = new WebProxy(proxySettings.Server, Int32.Parse(proxySettings.Port))
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxySettings.Username, proxySettings.Password, proxySettings.Domain)
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          throw new Exception("Error");
        }
        return proxy;
    }
```

and the class:

```
public class ProxySettings
{
    public bool ProxyActive { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(url);
client.Options.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1");
```

Don't forget `.Options.Proxy`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.