# GET Request with proxy c#

Tags: c#, proxy, request, httpclient, apiclient

I am currently using a APIClient to send GET Requests:

```
public async Task<Model.Rootobject> Stock()
    {
        var apiClient = new APIClient();
        Task<string> getResponseTask = apiClient.GetAsync("website");
        string json = await getResponseTask;
        Model.Rootobject Model_ = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model.Rootobject>(json);
        return Model_;
    }
```

This is so I can deserialize my response. I want to be able to send a GET request using a proxy; is there a way to do it or do I have to switch to a HTTPClient and use that with a proxy?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried RestSharp? There's an easy way (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23755934/1378507) to set a proxy with it and it's great for RESTful APIs.

Comment: Looks good, I'll try it out. Thanks @WashingtonA.Ramos