# How to Test a Proxy with C#?

Tags: c#, testing, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Connecting Through Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy)

I've tried doing this for a long time in many different ways but nothing seems to work. Essentially I want to create a proxy checker in C# that checks it by actually going to a page (e.g. http://google.com/ncr) and determines from there if it got there or not.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Theres already so many examples for it. Just try setting your proxy in the following [MSDN code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a http proxy

```
bool OK = false;
try
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(Host, Port);
    wc.DownloadString("http://google.com/ncr");
    OK = true;
}
catch{}
```

Comment: this doesn't check completely, you should also check the result string content.