# Posting data through http, switch between proxies after each request

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, http-post

I am relatively new to C# especially in the web aspects of it.

Let's say I have the following:

```
string URI = "http://www.domain.com/post.php";
string params = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";
```

I understand I can post data like this:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, params);
}
```

But how do I use a proxy when posting this data?

I found this [Related Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1939025/1328014):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("1.1.1.1", 80);
myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
request.Proxy = myproxy;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

[WebClient.Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.proxy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is the property you are looking for:

```
WebProxy[] myproxies = new WebProxy[] { new WebProxy("1.1.1.1", 80), 
     new WebProxy("1.1.1.2", 80) };
var currentProxy = 0;

while (true)
{
   // set proxy to new one every iteration...
   currentProxy = (currentProxy + 1) % myproxies.Length;
   using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
   {
     wc.Proxy = myproxies[currentProxy]; 
     wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
     string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, params);
   }
}
```

Comment: what namespace should I include to use webproxy/

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito [WebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webproxy(v=vs.80).aspx) - first line says `Namespace: System.Net`...

Comment: @Alexie Levenkov, why do I get `::1` if i returned `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito it is *your* IPv6 address (equivalent of 127.0.0.1 in IPv4).

Comment: yeah, it means that I posted using my computer right? did I just use a proxy?

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito, maybe you aren't ? Have you configured your WebProxy objects the way you like (i.e. `BypassProxyOnLocal = false`)?

Comment: maybe not.. i'll try things out.