# C# Debugging error : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to crawl a website using proxy server. Here's my Code

```
try{
     HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(proxy+link);
     req.Timeout = 60000;//timeout 2 minutes
     req.UserAgent = AGENTLIST[agentCount];
     req.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;

                            //response
     HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
     Stream dataStream = res.GetResponseStream();
     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
     string html = reader.ReadToEnd();

     HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
     doc.LoadHtml(html);

     body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
    }catch(Exception e)
    { Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
      Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
      Console.ReadLine();
      }
```

I get this error

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ASP.osproxy_getpage_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\SharedCrawl\Dropbox\sharedcrawl\osproxy\GetPage.aspx:line 30
```

If I do this

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(link); //no proxy
```

I do not get error.

Can anybody explain what the error means?

Thanks
R

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy

Comment: Guess it means that the proxy is not allowing you to connect.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use proxys on WebRequests. You should use the [HttpWebRequest.Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) property.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
req.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress, proxyPort);
```