# Making my code run under a different IP address

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, impersonation

Good Day Guys,

I hope you can help me. I am working with a third party vendor that has a webservice that I invoke using C#. The issue I am having is that they allow only one of our machines to go through their firewall and currently that machine is our PROD server and they also give us the WSDL for the service. I was able to create a simulation service using svcutil and the WSDL. Now I need to get a real response during development and during test without testing in production. My question is - Can I make my code (in C#) impersonate my production server? Is there a way I can make my code make SOAP calls using the details of the PROD server so my calls can go through the firewall.

I would be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Install a webproxy to your PROD server

Answer (score 0):

As Eser suggested, using a proxy would work. The easiest way would be to:

1. Install Fiddler on your production server
2. Enable remote connections in fiddler (see below)
3. Change prodserver firewall to accept local connections on port 8888
4. Finally, [change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy) your application's proxy server to be prodserver:8888

[image]