# Using Fiddler to capture the interaction during Azure Active Directory login

Tags: ssl, fiddler, azure-active-directory

I cannot use Fiddler to see the interaction between the browser or my app with Azure Active Directory while performing a login. If I have Fiddler running with the option to decrypt the SSL communication, then the login fails. If I stop Fiddler then it proceeds. Had anyone been successful in doing the login while Fiddler capturing is on? thanks

Comment: Have you considered using Network tab on Google Chrome Developer tools or Firebug in Firefox? For browser scenarios, you will be able to see the requests, responses and redirects without Fiddler or any custom setup.

Comment: I haven't tried that for two main reasons: sometimes the authentication is not taking place inside Chrome or I have no way of accessing Chrome's developer settings from the authentication window.

Comment: Ultimately for Chrome to also be able to show the contents of SSL communication it would need to do the man-in-the-middle scenario. that is where the problem occurs, i believe

Comment: I agree that the for the app scenario, Chrome dev tools cannot be used. However, for browser scenario Chrome doesn't need to a man-in-the-middle because SSL has already terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You could install Fiddler on a VM an open the fiddler port. Then force the traffic via a proxy. (or [C# Connecting Through Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy))

For example;
https://gist.github.com/mikeblakeuk/8fa9308ac06f6a8617aca99f4ac36fe7

`var webRequestHandler = client.HttpMessageHandlers.OfType<WebRequestHandler>().LastOrDefault();
        if (webRequestHandler != null)
        {
            webRequestHandler.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl, true)
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true
            };
        }`