# How to connect to a SQL Server database using the proxy network on my university?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, proxy

I need to connect to a database hosted online, I've successfully connected to the database using the network on my place, but there is a proxy on my university and I need to find a way to connect to the DB using this network, using C# as programming language, Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy

Comment: Checked it, didn't work for me