# C# How to set up Webproxy with NTLM Authtification

Tags: c#, webclient, webproxy, defaultnetworkcredentials, ntlm-authentication

i wanna set up a webclient with a NTLM authtification proxy, but i have some Problems to hand over the DefaultCredentials. This is my current solution, but it doesn’t work.

```
        textBox.Text = "";
        IWebProxy proxy = System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebClient client = new WebClient
        {
            Proxy = proxy
        };
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        textBox.Text = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```

Here are some referencing Links thatI read, but nothing work for me:

[How should I set the default proxy to use default credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299940/how-should-i-set-the-default-proxy-to-use-default-credentials)

[C# Connecting Through Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy)

do you have any idea to fix this?