# How to follow a user with InstaSharp in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, instasharp

I have a problem with following a user on Instagram with InstaSharp
Here is my code:

```
private async void Follow()
{
    var followMe = await api.FollowUserAsync(userID);
    if (followMe.Succeeded)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Followed");
    }
    if (!followMe.Succeeded)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(followMe.Info.Message);
    }
}
```

And when I call this method in the messageBox it says feedback_required.
How can I fix this?

Also : other functions like Unfollow Login LogOut are working fine I just have problem with Follow function.

Comment: Have you tried googling the error code? I seem to find plenty of solutions, like [here](https://www.gramto.com/article/fix-instagram-feedback-required-error/)

Comment: @xdecdec thanks for link but i dont use Gramto and none of the suggested ways helped me. other functions like Unfollow Login LogOut are working fine i just have problem with Follow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some specific countries ip's will banned in situation like this as you said.

You can use proxies inside your program for this problem if your customers are from those countries.

[C# Connecting Through Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1939025/6174449)

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("[ultimate destination of your request]");
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy("[your proxy address]", [your proxy port number]);
myproxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
request.Proxy = myproxy;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by changing the proxy server. It seems Instagram was banning my IP for no reason!