# C# first call to https api is so slow, but python is ok

Tags: c#, https

In my C# dotnet desktop application, I use restclient lib to call my https API, the first call after user logon always requires more than 10 seconds! I have tried everything I can find by google:

```
try
{
    // Equal to: ipconfig /flushdns
    bool res = Win32API.DnsFlushResolverCache();
    _log.InfoFormat("DnsFlushResolverCache returns {0}", res);
}
finally
{
    //nothing to do.
}

System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

client = new RestClient(endpoint);
client.Proxy = null;
client.BaseHost = server_host;

client.AddDefaultHeaders(headers);
// ignore certificate trust
client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
client.Timeout = _restClientTimeout;

... //url is https://192.168.1.1/api/xxx

            DateTime beginat = DateTime.Now;
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(beginat);
_log.InfoFormat("timespan: {0} seconds.", span.TotalSeconds)
```

Comment: Does `HttpClient` exhibit the same behaviour?

Comment: If the delay is 30 seconds then you probably have the Proxy setting true.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938990/c-sharp-connecting-through-proxy

Comment: I don't need proxy.